# Visual Studio for Mac build failure involving System.Runtime version

Tags: .net, visual-studio, visual-studio-2017, .net-core

I have a repository which contains a solution with a single ASP.NET Core 2.0 project. I have two Macs, each with the same version of Visual Studio for Mac Community Edition installed (7.3 build 797.) The project in the repository builds and runs perfectly on system A, but it fails on system B with 12 errors resembling the error shown in this screenshot:

[image: A screenshot of the error.]

The main one in text:

```
Assembly 'System.Collections' with identity 'System.Collections,
Version=4.1.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a'
uses 'System.Runtime, Version=4.2.0.0, Culture=neutral,
PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a' which has a higher version than
referenced assembly 'System.Runtime' with identity 'System.Runtime, 
Version=4.1.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f711d50a3a' 
(CS1705)
```

I have no leads. I'm not sure what other information to post because I don't know what's relevant to the failure. Even just a hint would be of great help.

Comment: Run `botnet --info` to see if different .NET Core SDK are used.